# Restoring placeholder value to a search box after reset has been clicked

Tags: javascript, html, forms, reset

I am editing some javascript that has a search box with a variable as follows

```
var secondSearchTerm = $('#2nd-search').val();
```

In the HTML code '2nd-search' has a placeholder 'Enter search term'

I also have a reset button that clears the search as follows:

```
 $("#2nd-reset-btn").on("click", function () {
   return myNetwork.resetSecondSearch();
 })
```

What I would like to do is to get the search box to re-populate with the placeholder when reset is clicked. Right now the last entered term remains in the search box.

Any ideas on how I can edit the code to do this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi refer this link https://plnkr.co/edit/EtLmby5BdD5Yn70EIBRD?p=preview

js

```
// Add your javascript here
$(function(){

$("#reset").on("click", function () {     
   return $('#username').val('');
 });

});
```

html

```
<input type="text" name="name"  id = "username" placeholder="uname"/>
<button id="reset">Reset </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set the value to blank & take the focus away from the input(As some browsers hide placeholder on focus). The placeholder will be visible again. Try the following:

```
$("#2nd-reset-btn").on("click", function () {
   secondSearchTerm.blur();
   return secondSearchTerm.val('');
 })
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with pure JS only

**Given the initial value**

```js
function reset() {
  var initialValue = 'Enter your search term.';
  var query = document.getElementById('myquery');

  query.value = initialValue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myquery" />
<input type="button" id="reset" onclick="reset()" value="Reset" />
```

**Given the placeholder**

```
function reset() {
  var query = document.getElementById('myquery');
  query.value = '';
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="myquery" />
<input type="button" id="reset" onclick="reset()" value="Reset" />
```